# Verifying if user input as value exists in column using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, cursor

I am trying to verify whether a value inserted by a customer exists in the field.

```
import arcpy
import os
import sys


#Set the work space
arcpy.env.workspace = "Y:\Milad\GeometricNetworkAnalysis"
path= arcpy.env.workspace

#http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/data-access-using-cursors.htm
user_boundary = raw_input("Insert the number of the Node? ")
Table = "RFNodeBoundary.shp"
field = ['Name']

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Table, field) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        #print (u'{0}'.format(row[0]))   #this is working
        if user_boundary in cursor:
            print "your node is here."
        else:
            print "The node is not in the database."
```

The code returns "The node is not in the database." whether the node exists in database or not.

How I can fix the problem?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You have an ArcGIS 10.0 tag but are using ArcPy.da cursors which were only introduced at 10.1.  Please update your tags so that they correctly reflect what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the where clause will create a cursor that will only have the rows in the table that meet that condition(the user boundary).

The cursor object is iterable so it will have a next method(this is what is called internally on the for loop). So by calling the next we know if there is at lease one row in our table that meets our condition with out iterating over the entire table or all the rows that may have the user boundary.

Update: Use @Vince's suggestion to use a where clause

```
import arcpy
import os
import sys


#Set the work space
arcpy.env.workspace = "Y:\Milad\GeometricNetworkAnalysis"
path= arcpy.env.workspace

#http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/data-access-using-cursors.htm
user_boundary = raw_input("Insert the number of the Node? ")
Table = "RFNodeBoundary.shp"
field = ['Name']
where_clause = "Name='{}'".format(user_boundary)

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Table, field, where_clause) as cur:
    try:
        cur.next()
        print "your node is here."
    except:
        print "The node is not in the database."
```

Comment: Thank you @Sqyanchy but unfortunately it does not work. With `if user_boundary == row[4]:`  I get this: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\GeometricNetworkAnalysis\GeometricNetworkAnalysis.py", line 18, in <module>
    if user_boundary == row[4]:
IndexError: tuple index out of range`                                                                                            With `if user_boundary == row[0]:` it just continue to return "The node is not in the database."

Comment: The row array will have the same number of indices as the *field* object so you can only access the 0 index b/c there is only one value in the *field* array. The for loop will iterate over every entry in you shape file so that is why this is printing so many times. I have updated the answer so that it will only print once saying if it has found it or not.

Comment: I believe you could also switch from `if user_boundary in cursor:` to `if user_boundary in row:`, but this would print as many times as there are rows. (See @Squanchy's code and comment above). Your existing code was looking at the entire cursor (all of the rows), as many times as there are rows.

Comment: Excellent. It worked. I am really appreciative. Thank you very much

Comment: How about printing just once after not finding the value?

Comment: How about using the `where_clause` parameter (after building an index on the column), so you don't have to waste time pulling rows you don't need.

Comment: @Vince this is a great idea. Let me work on it and I will be back